# Getting Error when fetching data from backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, async-await, axios

Error: Network Error at createError (createError.js:16) at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)

I am getting the above error when I am trying to fetch data from backend which I created.

I have written the below code in my actions,

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {GET_PEOPLE} from './types'
export const startGetPeople = () => async(dispatch) => {
try {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/people')
    dispatch({
        type: GET_PEOPLE,
        payload: res.data
    })
} catch (error) {
    console.log("error from getpeopleAction",error)
```

I am able to fetch data from that API in Postman.

Postman response :-

```
[
{
    "_id": "60a8b70be6384c8052fcc2e0",
    "name": "chan",
    "company": "micro",
    "profile": "uploads\\old.png",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "60a8b80fe6384c8052fcc2e1",
    "name": "tucker",
    "company": "honda",
    "profile": "uploads\\employee.png",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "60a8b84be6384c8052fcc2e2",
    "name": "emma",
    "company": "techsoft",
    "profile": "uploads\\girl.png",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "60a8c004e6384c8052fcc2e3",
    "name": "amy",
    "company": "tec in",
    "profile": "uploads\\lady.jpg",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "60a8d07627915c1e2429a8a2",
    "name": "tom",
    "company": "mil tech",
    "profile": "uploads\\tom-hardy.jpg",
    "__v": 0
}]
```

Action type file:-

export const GET_PEOPLE = 'GET_PEOPLE'

Comment: share your postman response and the type struct for GET_PEOPLE

Comment: Now I have added them in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this block below:

```
async startGetPeople() {
  let response = () => {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/people').then(response => {
      resolve(response);
    });
  });
 };
 let result = await response();
 return result.data
}
```

Comment: Now Getting Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch and also " Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/api/people' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. "

Comment: Thanks for your response used CORS packge to resolve cors error now it's working fine.

Comment: `fetch` already returns a `Promise` so I don't see why you would need to wrap it in an another `Promise`.  Aren't those first 8 lines the same as `const result = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/people');`?